# Tomcat websocket echo app

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I am fairly new to websockets and am pulling my hair out. I am using the echo app as a template. I have created a project in eclipse called echo and have placed the source for EchoAnnotation.java and EchoEndpoint.java (http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/websocket/echo/) in the appropriate place.

I have also created an echo.xhtml file and placed it there as well (http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/webapps/examples/websocket/echo.xhtml?view=log).

I had to find the web.xml here: [Tomcat 8 Examples: Missing Configuration Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723818/tomcat-8-examples-missing-configuration-step) and am using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0"> 
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>echo.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I run my ant build script to turn this into examples.war and deploy it to my tomcat 8 webaps directory. I hit this URL: `http://localhost:8080/examples/echo.xhtml` and the page comes up.

the problem is that as soon as I click connect, I get a message indicating the server closed the connection.

Did I miss a setup step?

Just found that someone else is having the exact same problem: [How to make Tomcat 8 websocket example works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500384/how-to-make-tomcat-8-websocket-example-works?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to the download file for tomcat 8.05 and pulled the examples webapp out of the tarball and that is working fine. I'll just start playing with that.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that as soon as I click connect?
Where is your click button?

Comment: On the echo.xhtml that I downloaded from the examples.